# Regex to find a expression followed by whitespace, #, @ or end of input

Tags: regex

I want to find all instance of word (say myword), with the added condition that the word has whitespace, "@", "#" afterwords, or is the end of input.

Input string:
`"myword# myword mywordrick myword@ myword"`

I want the regex to match everything besides mywordtrick -

```
myword#
myword 
myword@
myword
```

I am able to match against the first 3 with `myword[@#\s]`

I thought `myword[@#\s\z]` would match against all 4, but I only get 3

I try `myword[\z]` and get no matches
I try `myword\z` and get 1 match.

I figure \z inside a [] doesn't work, because [] is character based logic, rather than position based logic.

Is there a way to use a single regex to match the expressions I am interested in? I do not want to use both `myword[#@\s]` and `myword\z` unless I really have to.

Comment: `\z` means "end of string", so at the point after the very last line. For the "end of line" (for each line), use `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
myword(?:[@#\s]|$)
```

It matches the string `myword` along with the symbols only if it's followed by `#` or `@` or `\s` or `$`. `$` means the end of the line.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO9sJ8)

Comment: This will match space also after 2nd `myword`

Comment: he wants to match the space also. isn't it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj you interpreted the question correctly, I am waiting to be able to accept the answer

Comment: Alright I stand corrected but @Maudicus it's not clear from your expected result (and I checked by clicking on Edit of your question) that you want to capture `"myword "` instead of `"myword"` in output.